# Saving stream of bytes to file in Swift on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm using `FileHandle` to write stream of bytes to the mp4 file.

My data source allows me to input `bytesOffset` which is basically the current size of the file (if 0 it starts from the beginning, if more then it continue to save until reaches end).

I want to implement restart functionallity, but when `write` gets interrupted, the file exist, but size is always 0 KB.

Do you know any way to solve this or know any library which could help me with implementing this?

Comment: show some code, otherwise it's hard to tell if the problem is in the code, or for example in the used libs

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shamik framework for that.